# Fullpage.js - Video + Background in same section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I'm working with the Fullpage.js system for my site. 
Following problem is that I can't seem to get my background image to go over the video showing.

With the .layer class it's possible to get text over the video. But It doesn't work for a background-image.
Or I can't seem to get it to work.

I already contacted the fullpage.js github and they say it's CSS related period.

code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thpage', '5thpage'],
    sectionsColor: ['#C63D0F', '#1BBC9B', '#7E8F7C', '#1BBC9B', '#C63D0F'  ],
    verticalCentered: true,
    css3: true,
    afterRender: function(){


     //playing the video
     $('video').get(0).play();
    }
    
   });
  });
 </script>
```

```css
#myVideo{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
   background-color: black; /* in case the video doesn't fit the whole page*/
    background-image: /* our video */;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
     object-fit: cover; /*cover video background */
     z-index:1;
 }
  #layer2{
  background-image:url(imgs/TOHA.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-attachment:fixed;
  background-size:cover;
     background-position:center;
  background-size:;
  z-index:9999;
 
 }

/* Layer with position absolute in order to have it over the video
 * --------------------------------------- */
 #section0 .layer{
  
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 43%;
  
 }

 /*solves problem with overflowing video in Mac with Chrome */
 #section0{
  overflow: hidden;
 }
```

```html
<div class="section " id="section0">
    <div class="layer2"></div>
    <div class="layer">
   <h1>Fixed elements</h1>
   <p>Create your own headers and footers</p>
  </div>
    
     <video autoplay loop muted controls id="myVideo">
   <source src="imgs/flowers.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="imgs/flowers.webm" type="video/webm">
  </video>
  
 </div>
```

Comment: The place to start is with you CSS.   For example, you have an ID selector in your CSS #layer2, but the markup declares a class called layer2.    Therefore, it appears your intention was to use a class selector in your CSS, i.e   .layer2   Similar remark for other elements.

Comment: Sorry I copied something wrong clearly because the #layer2 is in my html an ID and not a Class. And that didn't changed anything. What other elements are you reffering to?

Comment: Have you tried moving the layer2 element after the video in the HTML markup?

Comment: yep also didn't work placed it everywhere even tried another section didn't work too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to create this effect.
First create a container for your video, if you already have it, than use it:

```
<div class="videoContainer">... Content will go here ...</div>
```

Then style your `.videoContainer` like this, for example:

```
.videoContainer{
    width:80%; /* This will be the size of your background, let's say it's 80% */
    height:200px; /* This is size too */
    position: relative; /* This will be necessary to contain the image that will be created next to avoid it to go outside the .videoContainer because of its position:absolute; */
}
```

Then create your overlay image/background like this:

```
.bgOverlay{
    background:url('https://shechive.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/a-mc-random-12.jpg');
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

### All together should look something like this:

**[Online Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zjdbmz2L/)**

```
<div class="videoContainer">
    <iframe width="100%" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0y-yhCav8Zw?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <div class="bgOverlay"></div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.videoContainer{
    width:80%;
    height:200px;
    position: relative;
}

.bgOverlay{
    background:url('https://shechive.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/a-mc-random-12.jpg');
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: though it works, it works against the functionality of the full page system. When I adjust the width it conflicts with the fullpage system of working with withs and heights. So it's not really an option to use this. Isn't there a way to get the same result but in the fullpage.js section way.

Comment: You need to wrap all of the `<div class="videoContainer"> ... </div>` content and paste it inside of YOUR `<div class="section" id="section2"></div>` like on this example: http://jsfiddle.net/gpjg283v CSS for the iframe is on the CSS box situated on the right side of the Jsfiddle

Comment: Hey Chun, no it isn't it was in my section in the html markuup
`  <div class="section" id="section0">

      <video autoplay loop muted controls id="myVideo">
   <source src="imgs/sunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="imgs/sunny.webm" type="video/webm">
  </video>
     <div class="layer">
      <div id="backgroundimg"> </div>
   <h1>Fixed elements</h1>
   <p>Create your own headers and footers</p>
    </div>`

Comment: It isn't fixed. There should be a comma between Isn't and it.

Comment: oh I'm sorry I thought you were saying that the problem was fixed, Well that was only an example, because obviously I don't know in which section you were trying to implement this cause you didn't told it in your question. It was only an example, now regarding the example you can now do that for your own code. If you need this for `<video>` instead of `<iframe>`, just change the `.videoContainer iframe` for `.videoContainer video` and also exchange the `width` for `min-width`, like on this example on Jfiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/gpjg283v/2/**

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for my thanks to help of Chun.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    anchors: ['firstpage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thpage', '5thpage'],
    sectionsColor: [ '#1BBC9B', '#7E8F7C', '#1BBC9B', '#C63D0F'  ],
    verticalCentered: true,
    css3: true,
    afterRender: function(){


     //playing the video
     $('video').get(0).play();
    }
    
   });
  });
</script>
```

```css
.videoContainer{
  position:absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-size:100% 100%;
  background-size:contain;
  background-position:center center;
  object-fit:cover;
  z-index:50;

 
}
 .bgOverlay{
     background:url('https://shechive.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/a-mc-random-12.jpg');
     position:fixed;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:35% 35%;
  background-position:center bottom 90px;
     top: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:100;
}
    #section0 .layer{
  
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 43%;
  
 }
```

```html
      <div class="section" id="section0">
   <div class="videoContainer">
         <video autoplay loop muted class="videoContainer">
          <source src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0y-yhCav8Zw?autoplay=1" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0y-yhCav8Zw?autoplay=1" type="video/webm">
                
         </video>
         
     </div>
  <div class="layer">
   <h1>TOHA</h1>
   
  </div>
        <div class="bgOverlay"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You're welcome @LazyFatTree. If you have some time to spare please consider marking my answer as correct =)